# XMLUnit RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier not working

Tags: java, xmlunit

Hi I'm trying to use XML Units    RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier   , But my below test is failing. When I interchange the value of foo3 and foo2 in below test xml file , the test is passed with true (for diff.similar()) . Not sure what the issue is.RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier   is only going to specific depth ?

**Contorl :**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a>foo</a>
            <a>foo1</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a>foo2</a>
            <a>foo3</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a>bar</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


**Test:**
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a>bar</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a>foo3</a>
            <a>foo2</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a>foo1</a>
            <a>foo</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


DetailedDiff detDiff = new DetailedDiff(diff);
diff.overrideElementQualifier(new RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier());

XMLUnit.setNormalizeWhitespace(true);
System.out.println("Similar? " + diff.similar());
```

Answer (score 1):

Things seem to work better when you swap the foo2 and foo3 lines, but only by accident.  If you tell XMLUnit to not randomly match elements it shouldn't match with

```
XMLUnit.setCompareUnmatched(false);
```

you will see a completely different picture.

```
[different] Expected presence of child node 'tr' but was 'null' - comparing <tr...> at /table[1]/tr[1] to  at null
[not identical] Expected sequence of child nodes '3' but was '1' - comparing <tr...> at /table[1]/tr[2] to <tr...> at /table[1]/tr[1]
[different] Expected presence of child node 'null' but was 'tr' - comparing  at null to <tr...> at /table[1]/tr[2]
```

`RecursiveElement...` picks the `tr`s with the nested bar texts but doesn't consider the other two `tr`s comparable at all.  XMLUnit just picks them because there are no other matches (and picking elements in order is the default fallback unless you use the flag above.

`RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier` only works if the child elements appear in the exact same order - which is not the case for the children of the `tr`s and not even for the children of the `td`s.